# How to do arithmetic operations on Thymeleaf variable after declare it with default value?

Tags: java, templates, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Here I have declared variable with name someVariable and assign default value 10:

```
<p th:with ="someVariable=10">
        <p th:text ="someVariable=${someVariable}+${someVariable}"> </p>
        <p th:text ="${someVariable}"> </p>
</p>
```

After that I am changing value of variable but I am geting error.

How to change value of Variable after declare it in Thymeleaf ?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
<p th:with="someVariable=10">
    <p th:with="someVariable=${someVariable + someVariable}">
        <span th:text="${someVariable}"></span>
    </p>
</p>
```

Comment: I got output 20 because I print value of someVariable in inner P tab but I when I print again value of someVariable I got result 10

Comment: Because that is out of the scope!